# Gorm how to select nested fields within SELECT or ScanRow methods?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

### Summary

Trying to mappaing the below fields:

```
"id", "views", "product", "product.title", "product.price", "product.category.name"
```

Using a custom `struct`

```
    type Result struct {
        Id         string                `json:"id"`
        Thumbnails []models.ProductImage `json:"thumbnail"`
        Views      uint64                `json:"views"`
        Title      string                `json:"title"`
        Price      uint64                `json:"price"`
        Shop       string                `json:"shop"`
        Country    string                `json:"country"`
        Category   string                `json:"category"`
    }
Relevant fields:
type Publication struct {
    ID        string    `gorm:"not null"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `sql:"DEFAULT:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `sql:"DEFAULT:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
    Views     uint64    `gorm:"default:0" json:"views"`
    Product Product `gorm:"foreignkey:ID" json:"product"`
}

type Product struct {
    ID           string `gorm:"not null"`
    Title        string
    Price        uint64
    Category     ProductCategory `gorm:"foreignkey:ID" json:"category"`
    State        string
    Description  string
    Availability string
    Brand        string
    Labels       []ProductLabel `gorm:"foreignkey:ID" json:"labels"`
    SKU          string
    Images       []ProductImage `gorm:"foreignkey:ProductId" json:"images"`
}
type ProductImage struct {
    ID        string
    ProductId string
    Name      string
}
```

Query method A:

```
pbs := []Result{}
    err = db.
        Debug().
        Preload("Product.Images").
        Select("id", "views", "product.images", "product.title", "product.price", "product.category.name").
        Model(&models.Publication{}).
        Limit(3).
        Where("created_at <= ?", time.Now()).
        Scan(&pbs).Error
```

Error displayed

```
Error 1054: Unknown column 'product.images' in 'field list'
```

Query method B:

```
rows, err :=db.
            Debug().
            Preload("Product.Images").
            Model(&models.Publication{}).
            Limit(3).
            Where("created_at <= ?", time.Now()).
            Rows()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error during querying")
        }
defer rows.Close()
        for rows.Next() {
            var pbs_model models.Publication
            r.db.ScanRows(rows, &pbs_model)
            prop := &Result{
                Id:         pbs_model.ID,
                Thumbnails: pbs_model.Product.Images,
                Views:      pbs_model.Views,
                Title:      pbs_model.Product.Title,
                Price:      pbs_model.Product.Price,
                Shop:       "Random shop",
                Country:    "Random country",
                Category:   pbs_model.Product.Category.Name,
            }
            pbs = append(pbs, *prop)
        }
```

But `images`field throws `null`

Already tried `r.db.Preload(Product.Images).ScanRows(rows, &pbs_model)`

### Note

By defining a new variable `publications := []models.Publication{}` I actually get the expected result.
Is there a `gorm` best practice method/function to query data for this particular case?

```
pbs := []Result{}
    publications := []models.Publication{}
    err = db.
        Debug().
        Preload("Product.Images").
        Model(&models.Publication{}).
        Limit(3).
        Where("created_at <= ?", time.Now()).
        Find(&publications).Error
    for _, publication := range publications {
        prop := &Result{
            Id:         publication.ID,
            Thumbnails: publication.Product.Images,
            Views:      publication.Views,
            Title:      publication.Product.Title,
            Price:      publication.Product.Price,
            Shop:       "Random shop",
            Country:    "Random country",
            Category:   publication.Product.Category.Name,
        }
        pbs = append(pbs, *prop)
```

### Expected result

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"thumbnail": [],
"views": 0,
"title": "Product Title A",
"price": 200,
"shop": "Random shop",
"country": "Random country",
"category": ""
},
{
"id": "2",
"thumbnail": [],
"views": 0,
"title": "Product Title A",
"price": 200,
"shop": "Random shop",
"country": "Random country",
"category": ""
},
{
"id": "3",
"thumbnail": [
{
"ID": "3",
"ProductId": "3",
"Name": "/path/cannabis_product_3.png"
},
{
"ID": "4",
"ProductId": "3",
"Name": "/path/cannabis_product_4.png"
}
],
"views": 0,
"title": "Product Title 3",
"price": 200,
"shop": "Random shop",
"country": "Random country",
"category": ""
}
]
```

### Resources consulted

1. Poor and helpless Gorm documentation `Select` and  `Advanced query` sections
2. SOF similar questions/answers but seems this is a particular case

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I am not getting the answer on any online forum. If you found it let me know.